# Hereditary and transitive set that is not a stage

Tags: logic, set-theory

In our lecture we defined a class $A$ to be transitive if for all $x \in A$ for all $y \in x$ it also holds that $y \in A$. Similarly hereditary classes are defined as for all $x \in A$ for all y, $y \subseteq x$ implies that $y \in A$.

We have shown that stages are hereditary and transitive in this sense. However my question would be whether there exists a set (i.e. not a 'real' class) that is hereditary and transitive but not a stage.

(Classes and as such sets in this case only consisting of sets themselves)

The definitions of all terms are according to [this](https://www.fi.muni.cz/%7Eblumens/st2.pdf) book

Comment: If I understand correctly, then for example $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ is transitive and hereditary, but eg its cardinality is not a power of $2$, so it's not one of the "stages" (aka it doesn't appear in the von Neumann hierarchy). You can extend this pattern to get a family of such sets.

Comment: A way to build hereditary transitive sets is to know that the Powerset is always hereditary and if x is transitive, then P(x) is transitive. So given any x, we take A = trcl(x) - "smallest transitive set which is a superset of x" and consider P(A) as our hereditary transitive set. To ensure that P(A) isn't a level, I propose P(3) as a hereditary transitive set, which is not a level. If it were, then P(3) = P(R(α)) and 3 = R(α) which is false.

Comment: Those are great answers. Thank you. If you wish to write them out as answers I'd gladly accept them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest (in terms of cardinality) example of a hereditary transitive set
which is not a stage in the von Neumann hierarchy is $\{\emptyset,
\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$.

This is because if $X$ is hereditary and transitive and $X$ has an element $y$
other than $\emptyset$ or $\{\emptyset\}$ then $y$ has an element $z$ which is
not $\emptyset$, so $\{\emptyset, y, z\} \subseteq X$.

The above set is not a stage because every stage has cardinality a power of two.
In fact, even stronger, every stage has a $2$-power-tower cardinality. But in
fact you can continue this pattern, to obtain sets $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},
\{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}, \dotsc\}$ of any finite cardinality
that's at least $3$. They'll never be one of the stages, even when their
cardinality doesn't exclude it, because, for example, for $\alpha \ge 3$, the
stage $V_\alpha$ contains a non-singleton nonempty set.

As Michael Carey observes in the comments, powersets are always hereditary. This
gives another nice class of examples, namely powersets of ordinals (or other
transitive sets). If $\alpha \ge 3$, then $\mathcal P(\alpha)$ is a transitive
hereditary set. It's never one of the stages, for example because
$\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\} \notin \mathcal P(\alpha)$ (this is because this set is $\{\{1\}\}$, and $\{1\}$ is not an ordinal, since the only singleton ordinal is $1 = \{\emptyset\}$), but $\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\} \in V_4$. Since $|V_3| = 4$, if $\mathcal P(\alpha)$ was a stage it would contain $V_4$.

---

I'd like to argue that actually a lot of this set theory stuff is slightly less
mysterious and scary than it might appear. Particularly - this question (finding a counterexample) is
brute-forceable, by interpreting it in a very concrete, computational way. (Please note that I don't mean to suggest this question was
easy or obvious or silly to ask - these things are way more obvious once you
know them, which is why I'm writing this answer!)

In set theory, in general, any set $X$ has a [*transitive
closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Transitive_closure),
which is the smallest transitive set containing $X$. The definition is pretty
computational - it just says "for each $x \in X$, for each $y \in x$, add $y$ to
$X$, and repeat this process $\omega$ many times". In my mind this is pretty analogous to
closure operations you might know from algebra like "the subgroup generated by
$X$" - you are simply enlarging $X$ to add all the elements that the definition of transitiveness says it must contain.

For a hereditarily finite set, this process stabilises after finite time, so you
could literally write a computer program to compute this.

To find the smallest hereditary set containing $X$, taking the full powerset
overshoots a little bit. The set $\bigcup_{y \in X} \mathcal P(y)$ is a
hereditary set containing $X$, and if $X$ is transitive, it's still transitive
(and clearly any hereditary set containing $X$ contains this set). So we can
explicitly compute the "transitive-hereditary closure" of $X$, by taking the
transitive closure, and then taking the union of powersets of each element. This "hereditary closure" operation is in very similar spirit to the transitive closure - it's simply what you get if you add "all subsets of elements of $X$" to $X$. (We got a bit "lucky" here that the hereditary closure preserves transitiveness, and also that hereditary closure stabilises after one round of adding elements. If this wasn't the case, then we could still compute the transitive-hereditary closure by alternating between taking the transitive closure and hereditary closure, until *that* process stabilises.)

Therefore, to find a transitive hereditary set, just pick your favourite
hereditarily finite set $X$, and see what this computation gives you. In general
this will often not be a stage. You can literally write a computer program to
do this! In fact, I have done this. Here it is:

```
import itertools
import collections

class STSet(frozenset):
    """
    "Set-Theory set." This is a representation of a hereditarily finite set of
    sets.

    This is a thin wrapper around a "frozenset of frozensets".
    """

    @classmethod
    def fromlist(cls, elts):
        return cls(map(cls.fromlist, elts))

    @classmethod
    def neumann(cls, n):
        """
        The nth stage in the von Neumann hierarchy.
        """
        res = cls()
        for _ in range(n):
            res = res.powset()
        return res

    @classmethod
    def neumann_ordinal(cls, n):
        """
        The von Neumann ordinal for n.
        """
        res = cls()
        for _ in range(n):
            res = res | STSet([res])
        return res

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{{{', '.join(str(x) for x in self)}}}"

    def __or__(self, other):
        return STSet(super().__or__(other))

    def powset(self):
        t_elts = tuple(self)
        return STSet(
            map(STSet,
                map(itertools.compress,
                    itertools.repeat(t_elts),
                    itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=len(t_elts)))))

    def TCL(self):
        """
        Transitive closure.
        """
        prev = self
        self = self._TCLstage()
        while self != prev:
            prev, self = self, self._TCLstage()
        return self

    def _TCLstage(self):
        return self | STSet(y for x in self for y in x)

    def HCL(self):
        """
        Hereditary closure.
        """
        res = STSet()
        for x in self:
            res |= x.powset()
        return res

    def HTCL(self):
        """
        Hereditary-transitive closure.
        """
        return self.TCL().HCL()

    def is_hered(self):
        return all(x in self for y in self for x in y.powset())

    def is_trans(self):
        return all(x in self for y in self for x in y)

# the example from my comment
X = STSet.fromlist([[[[]]]])
print(X.HTCL())
assert X.HTCL().is_hered()
assert X.HTCL().is_trans()

# Michael Carey's example
Y = STSet.neumann_ordinal(3)
print(Y.powset())
assert Y.powset().is_hered()
assert Y.powset().is_trans()

V4 = STSet.neumann(4)

print(V4)

# making sure my reasoning about P(alpha) is now correct :)
# print(STSet.fromlist([[[[]]]]) in V4)
# print(STSet.fromlist([[[[]]]]) in STSet.neumann_ordinal(4).powset())
# print(STSet.fromlist([[[[]]]]) in STSet.neumann_ordinal(10).powset())
# print(STSet.fromlist([[[]]]) in STSet.neumann_ordinal(10).powset())

print("-" * 80)

# all transitive hereditary subsets of V_4, obtained by taking closures of all
# subsets of V_4. Also, count the number of times each one comes up by this
# process.
Zs = collections.Counter(Z.HTCL() for Z in V4.powset())

neumanns = {STSet.neumann(n) for n in range(5)}

print("the first five stages:")

for Z in neumanns:
    assert Z in Zs
    f = Zs[Z]
    print(f, Z)
    assert Z.is_trans()
    assert Z.is_hered()

print("-" * 80)

print("all hereditary transitive subsets of V_4 which are not a stage:")

for Z, f in Zs.items():
    if Z not in neumanns:
        print(f, Z)
    assert Z.is_trans()
    assert Z.is_hered()
    # if Z == Y.powset():
    #     print("^^^^")

print(f"there are {len(Zs)} hereditary transitive sets overall")
print(f"{len(neumanns)} of these were stages, so there are {len(Zs) - len(neumanns)} examples in total.")
print(f"there were {sum(Zs.values())} subsets of V_4 that were checked.")
```

It's a moderately simple Python program (it does require some understanding of
object-oriented programming in Python), which defines a set object, and then
finds all subsets of $V_4$ which are transitive and hereditary by a brute-force
search (namely, by computing all transitive-hereditary closures of subsets of
$V_4$). This program can surely be made cleverer and faster (for example - the
transitive closure operation can be defined directly by recursion, without the
costly "check if it's stabilised" step. There is also
a [famous
encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set#Ackermann_coding)
of hereditarily finite sets as natural numbers, which no doubt could offer some
performance improvements) but my point is that you don't need that - it runs in
about a second on my laptop.

Upon running, it produces $92$ examples. $5$ of these are stages -
namely, - $V_\alpha$ for $\alpha = 0, \dotsc, 4$.
I've separated these from the rest, which are all examples for
your question (I hope)! Each line of its output is a number $f$ (for
"frequency") and a transitive
hereditary subset $Z$ of $V_4$. The number $f$ is the number of subsets of $V_4$
of which $Z$ is the closure.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
the first five stages:
1 {}
1 {{}}
2 {{}, {{}}}
8 {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
32768 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all hereditary transitive subsets of V_4 which are not a stage:
128 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
512 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
16 {{}, {{{{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{{}}}}
128 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
2048 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}}
16 {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}}
32 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
512 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
2048 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
2048 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
512 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
2048 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
2048 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
2048 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}}
512 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
512 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
16 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}}
512 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
16 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}}
16 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
16 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
8 {{}, {{{{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}}}
128 {{}, {{{{}}}}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}}
8 {{}, {{{{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
32 {{}, {{{{}}}}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
32 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
512 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
1024 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
32 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
512 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
256 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
64 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
32 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
32 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{}}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}, {{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
4 {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}
16 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
128 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{{}}}, {{}}}}
32 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
32 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
32 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{{}}}, {{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{{}}}}, {{}, {{}}}}
16 {{}, {{{}, {{}}}}, {{{{}}}}, {{{}}}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}
there are 92 hereditary transitive sets overall
5 of these were stages, so there are 87 examples in total.
there were 65536 subsets of V_4 that were checked.
```

Interestingly the frequency with which each of these appears seems to always be
a power of two, and the frequency of $V_4$ is exactly half of the total number
of subsets of $V_4$. The theory of hereditarily finite sets (and sets in
general) can be pretty combinatorial! I am sure there are good combinatorial
reasons for these phenomena. I'm not particularly familiar with the
combinatorics here, and this is basically an entirely separate question, so I
won't attempt to explain this for the time being.

If you only wanted one example, then you don't need to do *all* of this
computation (nor do you have to write a program - you can do this perfectly well by hand for small examples). For example a good starting point would be to just compute the
transitive-hereditary closure of some sets like
$\{\emptyset\}$, $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, $\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$, and see if they
give stages every time. (This is basically how I came up with my example!)

This general idea might be of use to you in future, say if you ever find
yourself wondering "must every transitive set have property $\mathrm{xyz}$?". It
can be hard to think of examples of transitive sets if all you've been taught
about is the von Neumann stages and the von Neumann ordinals. But they're out
there!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but $\{\varnothing\} = 1$, so if $\alpha\geq2$, $\{1\}\in\cal P(\alpha)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, right of course *facepalm*. Thank you for pointing that out! I was probably never going to get that right when posting late in the evening, haha. I think I intended to say that $\{\{1\}\} \notin \mathcal P(\alpha)$, which I believe is true..

Comment: What a great answer. Thank you so much. I will definitely look into that more ! The programming seems like a great way of tackling the problem - will try to understand the above code.